# AutoMapper: How to map between Linq Expressions (Func<>)

Tags: entity-framework, expression, automapper

I am using repository pattern, so my repository just know about DTOs. It has to query the database with some filters using Entity Framework.
My problem is that Entity Framework only knows about DB model classes, so I have to 'automap' the *Expression* before being able to use them in any query.

I have declared a method that accepts a *Expression* as a filter.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<ItemDTO> GetItemsWithFilter(Expression<Func<ItemDTO, bool>> filter)
    {
        var filterDb = Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<ItemDB, bool>>>(filter);
        return dbContext.CONFIGURATIONS.Where(filterDb).Select(x => Mapper.Map<ItemDTO>(x));
    }
}

public class ItemDTO
{
   public int numero { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
} 

public class ItemDB //they are both the same, just for testing purpose
{
   public int numero { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}

//failing code 
 Repository.GetItemsWithFilter(x => x.name=="a");
```

I followed [tutorial](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).md) that says it is possible to map between expressions but i get some errors:

> "The specified type member 'name' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."}

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: I already checked that, but don’t get it to work and I do not know why

Comment: Consider posting [mcve]. The exception cannot be generated by the currently provided code because there is no `Description` property anywhere in the posted entity / DTO models.

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right. I tried to post the minimal code but I typed a wrong variable name. Now I have fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by including this extension method call:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.AddExpressionMapping();
    // Rest of your configuration
 });
```

Remeber to install nuget package **AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping**

```bsh
Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping
```